# Using the default approval workflow task form in a custom Visual Studio Workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I am making a custom approval workflow in VS, but I dont wan to create a custom infoPah form to create the task edit form. Is there any way to use the form that comes with the OOTB approval workflow??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try to specify the URN of OOTB InfoPath form in Elements.xml of your workflow solution.

Example:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Workflow
 Name="WorkflowProject1 - Workflow1"
 Description="My SharePoint Workflow"
 Id="1ac59aff-6d65-4e7c-9dc1-e84e7cbc6b3a"
 CodeBesideClass="WorkflowProject1.Workflow1.Workflow1"
 CodeBesideAssembly="$assemblyname$">
<Categories/>
<MetaData>
  <AssociationCategories>List</AssociationCategories>
  <!-- Tags to specify InfoPath forms for the workflow; delete tags for forms that you do not have -->
  <!--<Association_FormURN>[URN FOR ASSOCIATION FORM]</Association_FormURN>
   <Instantiation_FormURN>[URN FOR INSTANTIATION FORM]</Instantiation_FormURN>
  --><Task0_FormURN>urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:workflowInitAssoc:-AutoGen-2009-07-30T07:17:57:12Z:1033</Task0_FormURN><!--
  <Task1_FormURN>[URN FOR TASK (type 0) FORM]</Task1_FormURN>-->
  <!-- Modification forms: create a unique guid for each modification form -->
  <!--<Modification_[UNIQUE GUID]_FormURN>[URN FOR MODIFICATION FORM]</Modification_[UNIQUE GUID]_FormURN>
  <Modification_[UNIQUE GUID]_Name>[NAME OF MODIFICATION TO BE DISPLAYED AS A LINK ON WORKFLOW STATUS PAGE</Modification_[UNIQUE GUID]_Name>
  -->
  <StatusPageUrl>_layouts/WrkStat.aspx</StatusPageUrl>
</MetaData>
</Workflow>
</Elements>
```

You can check installed InfoPath Templates in Central Administration > General Application Settings > Manage Form Templates > when you click on template you could see the form URN.

Hope it helps.